# Azure Storage File Service - REST API usage in Android

Tags: android, rest, azure-storage

I am trying to use the Azure Storage File Service - REST API in my android application to get the list of directories/files under a share.

(In the Azure Storage Account) I am successfully able to create the required Share, Directory structure and files in the Azure File Storage using PowerShell and able to list the directories / files accordingly.

I am trying to use the following reference to build the http "GET" request from the application:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn166980.aspx

However I am struck at building the Authorization header for the Http Request. I am trying to follow the guidance given in

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx

But there is no clear procedure or method defined to create the authorization header from Android client. Appreciate any help to accomplish the task using Azure File Service Rest API in my android code.

Answer (score 1):

The [Azure Storage Android Library](https://github.com/azure/azure-storage-android) should handle all of this for you without you having to write REST level code.